# Ionic refresh tab menu in real time

Tags: ionic-framework, tabs, refresh, ionic5

My app has a tab page:

```
<ion-tabs>
<ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
<ion-tab-button tab="home">
  <ion-icon name="search-outline"></ion-icon>
  <ion-label>Cerca</ion-label>
</ion-tab-button>



<ion-tab-button tab="inserimento">
  <ion-icon name="add-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
  <ion-label>Inserisci</ion-label>
</ion-tab-button>

<ion-tab-button tab="servizi">
  <ion-icon name="shield-checkmark-outline"></ion-icon>
  <ion-label>Servizi</ion-label>
</ion-tab-button>



<ion-tab-button  *ngIf="this.messagginonletti == 0" tab="messaggi">
  <ion-icon name="mail-outline"></ion-icon>
  <ion-label>Messaggi</ion-label>
</ion-tab-button>

<ion-tab-button  *ngIf="this.messagginonletti > 0" tab="messaggi">
  <ion-icon name="mail-unread-outline"></ion-icon>
  <ion-label>Messaggi</ion-label>
</ion-tab-button>

<ion-tab-button tab="account">
  <ion-icon name="person-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
  <ion-label>Account</ion-label>
</ion-tab-button>
```

where "messaggi" tab has 2 different values, one if this.messagginonletti variabile is 0 and another one if this.messagginonletti is > 0.

How can i refresh tab menu to update messagginonletti value? I retrieve this value using a function:

```
retrieveMessages() {
   return new Promise((resolve =>{
  this.accsPrvds.postData(‘test.php').subscribe((res:any)=>{
//console.log(res);
this.messagginonletti = res.success;
});
}));
}
```

the value of tab menu is set when app starts, but I don't know how to update (refresh) it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it doesn't update, it should. You probably need to use `ngZone` where you are updating the data. But seems like the only thing that you change when `this.messagginonletti` changes is the icon of the tab. I wouldn't recommend changing the tab structure, only changing the icon here would suffice (or everything else that you want to change). so here is your fix:

```
<ion-tab-button  tab="messaggi">
  <ion-icon *ngIf="this.messagginonletti > 0" name="mail-unread-outline"></ion-icon>
  <ion-icon *ngIf="this.messagginonletti == 0" name="mail-outline"></ion-icon>
  <ion-label>Messaggi</ion-label>
</ion-tab-button>
```